# GUI Java specific letter counter of a read in file

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to programming and this is my first time ever using a GUI. The assignment is to input the name of a file and a specific character you want to count in the file and then press the count button and in the result box it will give you the number of times that number occurs. I started coding in the main first and then tried to transfer the code over to a GUI, but I'm having trouble with the conversion. I don't know how to change or what to change. I've been playing around with it for about three days now, any help is greatly appreciated.This is the code for the GUI so far, I did delete some of the pre generated code for this post.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class LetterCounterUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
}                       

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//used to get user input
    String fileName = jTextField1.getText();//getting file name from user
    String letter = jTextField2.getText();//specific letter to search for
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    File file = new File(jTextField1.getText());//opening file to read data
    Scanner data = new Scanner(file);

    String letter = jTextField2.getText();

    int tally = 0;//keeps track of number of times letter occurs

    while(data.hasNext())//will read file while it still has data to read
    {
        //making sure the computer is reading the correct file
        String oneLine = data.nextLine();//reads in one line

        for (int i =0; i<oneLine.length(); i++){
            char myChar = oneLine.charAt(i);//getting each character line by line
            String myString = ""+ myChar;//converting single character to a string 
            if (letter.matches(myString)){
                tally++;
            }
        }

    }
    data.close();//closes file

    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(tally));//converts tally to a string
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Next, ask an actual question, specify the problem you are having which is related to your code example

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you with the GUI.

```
package com.thegreatcounter;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

// Your JFrame object.
public class MainPanel extends JFrame {

    // the application entry point.
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // instantiate your UI
        MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();
        // make it visible
        mp.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Declare your components
    public JTextField dfFileName = new JTextField();
    public JTextField dfStringToFind = new JTextField();
    public JButton pbCount = new JButton("Count");

    // Constructor here, where you initialize your UI components.       
    public MainPanel() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("String counter");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("File"));
        panel.add(dfFileName);
        panel.add(new JLabel(" Text To Count "));
        panel.add(dfStringToFind);
        panel.add(pbCount);
        this.setContentPane(panel);

        dfFileName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,20));
        dfStringToFind.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
        pbCount.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));

        pack();

        // add logic to the push button.
        pbCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int count = countStringOccurrence(dfFileName.getText(), dfStringToFind.getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainPanel.this, "We have found " + count + " occurence", "Count", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
    * To count the string occurrence within the file.
    * @param file The full path to the file to be checked.
    * @param strToFind The string of which its occurrence will be checked.
    * @return Number of occurrence of strToFind inside the specified file.
    */
    public int countStringOccurrence(String file, String strToFind) {
        // put your logic here, to open and read the file
        // and return the number of string occurence in that file.
        // dont forget to close the file.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now, its your task to migrate the logic of string counter into the `countStringOccurrence` method there.

Learn how JFrame get constructed, Learn how to create and add your component into the frame, learn how add logic into the component.

I hope this helps.